# Buisness NET - Transparent Content Filter

Tags: active-directory, firewall, cisco, filtering

I am designing a network for a corporate company and would like some advice on a firewall/web filter to use that is free for HTTP and HTTPS.

The main network is gonna cost a bomb so want to use a free web filtering service.
I have heard and used squid but I think I need a transparent proxy. I have looked into them and dont think I can use AD single sign on for the users on the domain controller.

My plan was to have a web filter that set ACL's depending the security groups that users are in on active directory. Is there any way that this can be done in squid? Or are there any other free web filers that I can sit in transparent mode between the FIRST core switch and the router.

Here is a little explanation of the network stripped down for obvious reasons

`ISP - LEASE LINE IN
↓
CISCO ISR ROUTER GIG LAN
↓
PROPOSED PLACE FOR TRANSPARENT FILTER
↓
CORE 3750 CISCO (L3)
↓    ↓     ↓    ↓
MAIN DISTRIBUTION LAYER (4x3750 L3)
↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
ACCESS LAYER - FULL MESH (L2)`

Answer (score 0):

The proxy authentication is only possible on explicit proxies. When proxy is transparently deployed the browser does not know of proxy existence and thus *correctly* refuses to present user credentials to someone from nowhere asking to identify.

If you have an environment when one user is accessing the internet from one device (one IP) then theoretically it is possible to get the IP <-> user name mapping within proxy retrieved from the domain controller. Some *agent* is deployed on the DC then.

I am not aware of any free filter supporting it. The server side of it can look like https://github.com/diladele/active-directory-inspector (work in progress, GPLv3) but then you'd need to write the URL rewriter on the Squid side yourself. See the one deployed in https://www.diladele.com as inspiration.